# My 'datepart' argument isnt being accounted for in my DATEDIFF() function - SQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is my code:

```
SELECT fname, lname, DATEDIFF(Day, '2017-01-05', '2015-03-33') AS 'Days', DATEDIFF(year, '2017-01-05', '2015-03-33') AS 'Years'
FROM students;
```

I am trying to query the difference in years between the two dates and the difference in days between the two dates - everywhere I look I am told that this is a valid query, but for some reason I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at documentation for SQL Server or some other RDBMS.  In mysql, [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) takes two dates and returns the number of days the first date is after the second date.  There is another function [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) that lets you specify the units of the return, as you show, but has the dates in the other order.

So:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, '2015-03-31', '2017-01-05')
```

returns 1.  If you pass an invalid date, like your '2015-03-33', it will return NULL.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. In reality I was doing DATEDIFF('2017-01-05, dob) so I just making up a random date to simplify the query in question. I used TIMESTAMPDIFF but it got all of the years wrong by 3 years which is strange.

Comment: Wrong by 3 years?  Can you show what you did and a dob and what it produced?

Answer (score 0):

The function [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) takes 2 arguments while you pass it 3.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that the function took 3 arguments in SQL and only 2 in MYSQL. I was able to figure out the difference in years by using 
```
FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2017-01-05', dob)/365) AS 'Years'
```
Is there a way to calculate out the difference in days between the two dates without doing arithmetic in the query?

Comment: Please upvote the answers that were helpful and accept the best answer so we know you are all set.